# flutter pub run build_runner build is Deprecated

Tags: flutter, dart, build-runner, built-value

When I run `flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs`, I get this error:

```
Deprecated. Use `dart run` instead.
[INFO] Generating build script completed, took 169ms
[WARNING] ../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/built_value_generator-8.6.1/lib/src/dart_types.dart:65:21: Error: 'InvalidType' isn't a type.
    if (dartType is InvalidType) {
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/built_value_generator-8.6.1/lib/src/value_source_class.dart:497:20: Error: The getter 'name2' isn't defined for the class 'NamedType'.
 - 'NamedType' is from 'package:analyzer/dart/ast/ast.dart' ('../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/analyzer-5.7.1/lib/dart/ast/ast.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'name2'.
          if (type.name2.lexeme == 'Built') {
                   ^^^^^
[INFO] Precompiling build script... completed, took 547ms
[SEVERE] Failed to precompile build script .dart_tool/build/entrypoint/build.dart.
This is likely caused by a misconfigured builder definition.
```

So I run `dart run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs` instead and I get this error:

```
[INFO] Generating build script completed, took 172ms
[WARNING] ../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/built_value_generator-8.6.1/lib/src/dart_types.dart:65:21: Error: 'InvalidType' isn't a type.
    if (dartType is InvalidType) {
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/built_value_generator-8.6.1/lib/src/value_source_class.dart:497:20: Error: The getter 'name2' isn't defined for the class 'NamedType'.
 - 'NamedType' is from 'package:analyzer/dart/ast/ast.dart' ('../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/analyzer-5.7.1/lib/dart/ast/ast.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'name2'.
          if (type.name2.lexeme == 'Built') {
                   ^^^^^
[INFO] Precompiling build script... completed, took 570ms
[SEVERE] Failed to precompile build script .dart_tool/build/entrypoint/build.dart.
This is likely caused by a misconfigured builder definition.
```

I tried adding `gql: 0.13.0` to dependency_overrides but again I got the same error!

I'm using `Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.5, on macOS 13.2.1 22D68 darwin-arm64, locale en-US)` and `build_runner: ^2.4.5`

How do I fix it?

Comment: I think this problem is caused by flutter version not matching build runner. Can you provide more information?

Comment: I edited the question and added flutter and build_runner version

Comment: try adding analyzer: 5.13.0 in file pubspec.yaml
after run: 
```
flutter pub upgrade
flutter pub get 
flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can try to upgrade `build_runner` to latest version (currently is 2.4.8) by modify `pubsec.yaml`

```
dev_dependencies:
...
build_runner: ^2.4.8
...
```

or

```
flutter pub upgrade build_runner
```

and you should also clean all flutter caches by using

```
flutter clean
```

If it doesn't solve your problem, you will try

```
dart run build_runner doctor
```

to get more informations about this error.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the first pubspec.lock file.

then flutter clean
flutter pubget

**So it will generate both network.g.dart and pubspec.lock file**

flutter pub run build_runner build